# Dynamic resizing sprites in css

Tags: css, html, animation, sprite

I have a .png with several instances of a character that I intend to animate unsing javascript.

I have put this image inside a container div, like this:

```
<div class='mage'>
    <img src='images/mage.png' />
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.game .mage {
    width: 25%;
}
.game .mage img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

The container div, needs to resize according to the browser resolution and that's where I have a problem. In order to "cut" the sprite, I would net to set a fixed size for the container and use overflow: hidden, but I need it to be dynamic.

How can I resize the container and at the same time, "cut" the image inside of it?

Thank you.